# What does 'int kk = 2 | 3;' mean?

Tags: java, syntax, operators

I have been programming in java for a while but I have not met a strange expression

```
int kk = 2 | 3;
```

What does '|' mean in this expression? It seems hard to Google it.

I met it in source

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Why we need to use this?

Comment: Just a tip: instead of googling for "java |", google for "java operators".

Comment: Thanks all .but,why should we need to use this?

Comment: @topxebec: it can be used to work with individual bits, as well as for all kinds of interesting hacks: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [bitwise or](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html) - each result bit will be set if either or both inputs have a bit set in that position. 2 is 10 in binary, 3 is 11, so the result will also be 3.

Answer (score 4):

It's the ["`bitwise inclusive or operator`"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 2):

| is a [bitwise Operator](http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-bitwise-or.shtml). In your case, 2|3 will produce 3 as 2 is 10  and 3 is 11. `10 | 11 = 11`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html 
I think they are really very good tutorials on bit shift operators